# Recursive DFS graph traversal in Scala

Tags: scala, graph, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

I've seen the following code to traverse a graph depth first, in Scala:

```scala
def dfs(node: Node, seen: Set[Node]) = {
    visit(node)
    node.neighbours.filterNot(seen).foreach(neighbour => dfs(node, seen + node))
}
```

It seems to me this code is not correct as shown with the following example.

Nodes are 1, 2, 3.
Edges are 1 -> 3, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3

`dfs(1, Set.empty)` would visit node 1, then node 3, then node 2, then node 3 again because we don't maintain a global Set of seen nodes, but only add them in the recursive call to `dfs`.

What would instead be a correct implementation of DFS in Scala, without using mutable structures?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716313/graph-traversal-in-scala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471234/how-to-implement-a-dfs-with-immutable-data-types

Comment: I have another example here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/5ckJvLDQTvyRK1s1d7wZag/1 - Although, I don't remember if it was DFS or BFS.

Comment: Why not you check for `seen` right in `dfs` before `visit`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (though you might consider the foldLeft to be cheating a little):

```
def dfs(node: Node): Set[Node] = {
  def helper(parent: Node, seen: Set[Node]): Set[Node] = {
    neighbors(parent).foldLeft(seen)({ case (nowSeen, child) =>
      if (nowSeen.contains(child)) nowSeen else {
        visit(child)
        helper(child, nowSeen + child)
      }
    })        
  }

  visit(node)
  helper(node, Set(node)) 
}
```